# How to Get-Content of terraform (.tf) file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, terraform, terraform-template-file

How to fetch data of Terraform .tf file using PowerShell?
like we use for XML files:

```
(Get-Content -Path "C:\Desktop\strings.xml") -as [xml]
```

Is there is other way to fetch terraform file?

Answer (score 0):

Terraform has its own [configuration language](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/index.html). You need a custom parser for being able to parse that into PowerShell data structures. However, the documentation mentions that Terraform [supports JSON format](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/syntax-json.html) as an alternative to the native language. You should be able to import configuration files written as JSON like this:

```
Get-Content 'C:\Desktop\input.tf.json' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
```

or like this if you're running PowerShell v3 or newer:

```
Get-Content 'C:\Desktop\input.tf.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Comment: These commands not working ..giving below error
ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: .
At line:1 char:89
+ ... ari\Desktop\xyz.tf" | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
+                                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand

Comment: @Akshay Please actually *read* my answer instead of blindly copy/pasting code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind using an open source project I would suggest converting HCL to JSON by applying hcl2json library. The executable can be downloaded from here:
https://github.com/tmccombs/hcl2json/releases

Then you can invoke the process from PowerShell against your .tf or .tfvars file. The outcome should be this:

```
(& .\hcl2json_windows_amd64.exe -simplify "dev.shared.tfvars" | ConvertFrom-Json).key_vault_settings
```

[image]